# Angular JS thowing error even though controller is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am new to Angular JS and I am trying some examples... But I get a very weird exception when I try to load my app...

Here is my angular JS code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/Controllers.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
            <div ng-controller="HelloController">
                <h2>Hello {{helloTo.title}} !</h2>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="MyController" >
                <span ng-show="myData.showIt"></span>
                <span ng-hide="myData.showIt"></span>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Here is my controller code :

```
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
    $scope.helloTo = {};
    $scope.helloTo.title = "Test";
} );

angular.module("myapp1", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData.showIt = true;
});
```

Error logged by firebug:
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/ng/areq?p0=MyController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js
Line 83

I am using angular js version 1.2.5...

Comment: You have two, completely different modules here. One called `myapp` and one called `myapp2`. This is why `MyController` can't be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating **two different angular modules**, with one controller each, instead of ***one single  module with two different controllers***, which is what you want to do, just change your code to match this syntax:

```
angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        // ...
    })
    .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
        // ...
    });
```

Or this one:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myApp.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
    // ...
});

myApp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two modules, myapp and myapp2. myapp2 has a controller MyController which you are trying to use within the scope of myapp module, which is not possible.

you can define the MyController within myapp module. http://jsfiddle.net/g35tpy5q/1/

```
var myapp=angular.module("myapp", []);
myapp.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
    $scope.helloTo = {};
    $scope.helloTo.title = "Test";
} );

myapp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData.showIt = true;
});
```

or inject the myapp2 module inside myapp module http://jsfiddle.net/g35tpy5q/2/

```
angular.module("myapp2", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData.showIt = true;
});
angular.module("myapp", ["myapp2"]).controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
    $scope.helloTo = {};
    $scope.helloTo.title = "Test";
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here.

One, is that you have defined 2 different modules: "myapp" and "myapp1". Perhaps it's just a typo, and you meant for them to be the same.

Then, the second issue is that you are re-defining your module when you use `[]` for the second time:

```
angular.module("myapp", [])
```

This is a module **setter**.

Instead, use a module **getter** without the `[]`:

```
angular.module("myapp").controller("MyController", ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below will work. What you have to bare in mind is that everytime you define a new `angular.module` if you put `angular.module('myapp', [])` you are defining a new space that has no knowledge of any other module. If you then do `angular.module('myapp').controller()` that will attach the controller to the original module. Thus is being in its scope.

Notice the ommission of `[]` when defining the controller. The `[]` is for dependency injection, but in terms of `angular.module` defines a completely new module space.

Below is a way to actually properly modularise angular js.

```
angular.module("myapp.hello", []).controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
    $scope.helloTo = {};
    $scope.helloTo.title = "Test";
} );

angular.module("myapp.my", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData.showIt = true;
});

angular.module("myapp", [
    'myapp.hello',
    'myapp.my']);
```