# AngularJS : Error on Multiple Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning AngularJS. 
I tried with sample code, got error when I ran it. It's basic example I guess so.
Wasn't sure of the error.

On FireFox when I tried with FireBug, it show MyController1 not a function.

Any help appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController1">
    <div ng-click="myData1.doClick()">Click here</div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController1", function($scope) {
                $scope.myData1 = {};
                $scope.myData1.doClick = function() {
                    alert("clicked");
                }
            } );
</script>


<div ng-controller="MyController2" >
    <div ng-click="myData.doClick($event)">Click here for Event Coordinates</div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController2", function($scope) {
                $scope.myData = {};
                $scope.myData.doClick = function(event) {
                    alert("clicked: " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
                }
            } );
</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS thowing error even though controller is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753048/angular-js-thowing-error-even-though-controller-is-available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you doing `anuglar.module` again, you should not use `[]` as second parameter.
Using second parameter will reinitialize the module, and if second parameter is not passed, the same module is used.

So the code should be like this in your second script tag

```
angular.module("myapp")
        .controller("MyController2", function($scope) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.doClick = function(event) {
                alert("clicked: " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
            }
        } );
```